# Correctly setup Eslint Airbnb with VScode in Vue project

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

**This is my Vuejs code without linting.**

[image]

After I run

> npm run lint --fix

Code is like this

[image]

But again I do some change and press Control + C. It's get formatted to the old code and gives me back same linting errors.

I think my code is auto formatted when I hit the Control + C.

This is my Vue projects eslint.rc file

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/airbnb',
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
};
```

I didn't installed pretier plugin on VScode. But I installed Vueter plugin and Eslint pluggin.

My goal is to format my Vuejs code with Eslint Airbnb rules. When I save the code.
Right now it mess the code. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For me adding

```js
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
}
```

to my VS Code settings (`Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`) helped. Also: don't forget to reload/restart VS Code.